# How do deep CNNs handle problem of "perceptual aliasing" while visual place classification?

Tags: classification, deep-learning, feature-selection, conv-neural-network, pattern-recognition

Deep CNNs have achieved state-of-the-art performance in image classification. The underlying concept of place recognition is similar to image classification where the task is to classify or recognize a place. Two different places can have the same appearance, or the same place can appear drastically different at different times. We as humans even face difficulty in answering the question sometimes. This challenge is described as "perceptual aliasing". For a detailed description of the problem visit [here](http://eprints.qut.edu.au/105651/1/visual_place_recognition_a_survey_revised_final.pdf) (Lowry et al., 2016).

So my question is what are the approaches existing in the literature to address the problem of perceptual aliasing, specifically for methods using deep CNNs.

I'm aware that sequences of images (or videos) are sometimes used to eliminate the confusion, but I believe there must be a better way out.

Reference

Lowry, Stephanie, et al. "Visual place recognition: A survey." IEEE Transactions on Robotics 32.1 (2016): 1-19.

Comment: Perhaps a reference where the "perceptual aliasing" problem is described in more detail would help. Form your question, virtually any moderately difficult image classification problem can be described as a case of "perceptual aliasing".

Comment: @DanielLópez - Thank you for the comment. I've updated the question with a reference and link to it.